# import a CSV file to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm a beginner in nodejs and I'm trying to import a CSV file to MySQL
the connect work successfully but when I upload the file it gives an error

I do this :

```
    //use express static folder
app.use(express.static("./public"))
 
// body-parser middleware use
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
 
 
db.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
})
 
//! Use of Multer
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, './uploads/')    
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
 
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});
 
//! Routes start
 
//route for Home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
 
//@type   POST
// upload csv to database
app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single("uploadfile"), (req, res) =>{
    UploadCsvDataToMySQL(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename);
    console.log('CSV file data has been uploaded in mysql database ' + err);
});
 
function UploadCsvDataToMySQL(filePath){
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    let csvData = [];
    let csvStream = csv
        .parse()
        .on("data", function (data) {
            csvData.push(data);
        })
        .on("end", function () {
            // Remove Header ROW
            csvData.shift();
  
            // Open the MySQL connection
            db.connect((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    let query = 'INSERT INTO files (File-ID, File_Name) VALUES ?';
                    db.query(query, [csvData], (error, response) => {
                        console.log(error || response);
                    });
                }
            });
             
            // delete file after saving to MySQL database
            // -> you can comment the statement to see the uploaded CSV file.
            fs.unlinkSync(filePath)
        });
  
    stream.pipe(csvStream);
}
 
//create connection
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running at port ${PORT}`))
```

**but it's given me this error:**
ReferenceError: err is not defined
at C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\index.js:80:72
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Array. (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
at listener (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
at onFinish (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
at callback (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
at IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:341:22)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1294:12)
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-ID, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')' at line 1
at Packet.asError (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
at Query.execute (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket. (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Advanced\AdvancedSeE\dbmanager\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:304:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:279:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:218:10) {
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-ID, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')' at line 1",
sql: "INSERT INTO files (File-ID, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that a column name in you import files is not valid as you see at the end of you error message you have

```
INSERT INTO files (File-ID, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')
```

The column name File-ID should be changed (the minus sign in mysql is used for math and mean column FIle - column ID )

or using backtics

```
 INSERT INTO files (`File-ID`, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')
```

or avoidng the minus sign

```
INSERT INTO files (File_ID, File_Name) VALUES ('112', 'test2')
```

try edit the file and change the name properly

Comment: @SaraBB please ask further questions as separate questions, not as comments to an answer to a different question!